# Different ways to state the motivation of the definition of the product topology

Tags: general-topology, motivation, product-space

Suppose for every $i\in\mathscr I,$ $X_i$ is a topological space.

The product space has as its underlying set the product set $X =\prod \limits_{i\,\in\,\mathscr I} X_i$ and as its open sets product sets of the form $\prod\limits_{i\,\in\,\mathscr I} G_i$ where for every $i\in\mathscr I,$ $G_i$ is open and **for all except finitely many** $i\in\mathscr I,$ $G_i=X_i.$

Now suppose one is asked **why** the definition is that rather than something else ‒ for example, omitting the restriction to finitely many factors.

The answer that I know instantly is this: This is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence. That is, a net of points in $X$ converges to a point in $X$ if and only if for every $i\in\mathscr I,$ the projection of the net onto the $i$th factor space is a net that converges to the projection of the limit point onto that factor space.

However, there may be other and maybe even better ways of stating the motivation. What are they?

Comment: Mathematics has sometimes been said to be the most non-dogmatic of all subjects. (And at lower levels it is IN PRACTICAL EFFECT taught as the most dogmatic one, so that the view of it that the general public has. It is impossible to do otherwise as long as one has those infallible dogmas known as curricula and requirements. So it is obvious that the solution is to abolish those dogmas. But ignore this parenthesis and resume reading just after it.) But even in math courses taught non-dogmatically, DEFINITIONS are taught dogmatically, or ALMOST dogmatically, were "almost" means$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$exercises like the following are assigned, to be done AFTER the definition has been dogmatically presented: "Show that the product topology as thus defined is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence." The actual _logic_ of motivation has not been developed beyond the cave-man level, as far as I know, and does not govern the way textbooks and courses are organized at all, unlike the logic of theorems and proofs.

Comment: There are other kinds of product topology. The one you refer to is called the Tychonoff product topology. It has been found to be extremely fruitful. Initially it may have been an experiment ("What can we do if we try this?").

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : The "fruitful" part might be the interesting part, if it ca be shown to be true......

Comment: You could look at General Topoogy by R.Engelking, for example, to see how often Tychonoff products are used .

Answer (score 16):

In *any* category (such as the category **Set** of sets, the category **Grp** of groups, ...), the product of objects $A_i$, $i\in I$, is an object $P$, together with morphisms (called canonical projections) $\pi_i\colon P\to A_i$ such that for every object $X$ and family of morphism $f_i\colon X\to A_i$, there exists one and only one morphism $h\colon X\to P$ such that $\pi_i\circ h=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

Spelling this out for the category **Top** of topological spaces, leads to the well-known concrete construction.

Comment: ... and the uniqueness (up to unique isomorphism) of an object described by a universal property shows that we have no choice in deciding on features of a (categorical) product of topological spaces.

Comment: ... and coproducts become disjoint unions.

Answer (score 9):

The product topology is the coarsest topology for which each projection $\pi_i : X \rightarrow X_i$ is continuous.

This makes the product topology the categorical product in the category of topological spaces. That is, for any other space $Y$ with maps $f_i : Y \rightarrow X_i$ we get a unique map $f: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $\pi_i \circ f = f_i$.

Answer (score 4):

The two biggest reasons I can think of for why the product topology is defined this way:

- **Continuous functions** Given continuous functions $f_i:Y\to X_i$ for each $i\in I$, there is a unique continuous function $f:Y\to\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ such that $f_i=p_i\circ f$ for all $i\in I$, where $p_i:\prod_{j\in I}X_j\to X_i$ is the projection map. In fact, this uniquely characterizes the product topology.
- **Compact sets** If each $X_i$ is compact, then Tychnoff's theorem states that $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is compact. This is an extremely powerful theorem, and is equivalent to the axiom of choice. This is certainly not true under what some may see as a more "natural" topology on $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, i.e. the topology generated by $\{\prod_{i\in I}U_i:U_i\text{ open for each }i\in I\}$.

Comment: (+1) The "natural" topology you refer to has a name: the box topology. As for the first bullet, a bit of caution is required to correctly interpret the uniqueness clause: it uniquely determines the product topology once the underlying set and the projections have been chosen.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of definiteness, I will refer to the name I have seen most commonly used: the product topology is, as others have mentioned,  the Initial Topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology  with respect to the projections.

A dual concept is that of the Final Topology, which is the finest topology put on
the codomain in $f: Y \rightarrow X $ that makes the set continuous.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology.

As an example, the quotient topology is the final topology with respect to quotient maps.

Answer (score 0):

I note that the given definition seems to avoid invoking Choice -- I only have to provide an open set for a finite number of indices.  This might be a red herring.  (I would be interested if anyone has references that shed light on this thought.)

### Edit

Since there seem to be at least two readers who believe that ZF is capable of picking out elements of infinite Cartesian products of nonempty sets, more detail...

Let $\mathscr{I}$ be countably infinite, and let $X_i = X$, a nonempty topological space, for all $i \in \mathscr{I}$.  Let $T$ be the topology of $X$.  Then $P = $"$\prod_{i \in \mathcal{I}} X_i$" ($ = X^\omega)$ and $Q = $"$\prod_{i \in \mathscr{I}} T $" ($ = T^\omega$) are wffs that ZF cannot prove are sets.  ZF can prove  arbitrary finite Cartesian products are sets, but has no mechanism to identify an infinite Cartesian product as a set.  So, in particular, ZF cannot apply Foundation to $Q$, a basis of the box topology on whatever $P$ is, to get an arbitrary element of $Q$.  As soon as one adds a suitable axiom, for instance, the axiom of countable choice, these obstructions vanish.

However, let $Q' = $"$\prod^{(\text{finite})}_{i \in \mathscr{I}} T $", where the superscript "(finite)" means this is the collection of maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $T$ where, for each member of the collection, only finitely many elements of $\mathbb{N}$ have an image other than $X$.  Since finite choice is a theorem of ZF, we are able to construct the *set* of members of $Q$ with only the first $0$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$ not mapped to $X$, the *set* of members of $Q$ with only the first $1$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$ not mapped to $X$, and so forth by induction.  Via Comprehension, these sets can be assembled into the images of another function from $\mathbb{N}$, allowing ZF to show that $Q'$ is a set.  Since $T$ is nonempty, we know that the image of $1$ under this new map is nonempty.  Now ZF's Foundation permits "let $U \in T^\omega$".

So the product topology can be framed entirely in the setting of ZF (for countable products of spaces).  But the box topology already requires a choice axiom for the smallest infinite Cartesian product.

Comment: That the product set is in every case non-empty is equivalent to the axiom of choice. In _some_ cases it can be shown to be non-empty without that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Perhaps my point is unclear.  In the box topology, one *does* have to invoke Choice for "most" elements of the topology -- one has to supply a nontrivial choice of open subset for all infinitely many indices.  I'm not talking about emptiness, I'm talking about how much you have to extend ZF to even write down an open set.

Comment: @EricTowers: I don't see how choice factors into this. Standard product open sets are still open sets in box topology. It's just that there are more basic sets in the latter one. The only thing that could happen in absence of choice is that the two topologies could end up equal (for instance, if the whole product is empty), while assuming choice, the box topology is finer in nontrivial cases.

Comment: @tomasz : "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology."  I've just invoked countable choice because I've assumed countably many choices of open set in $X$.  "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ be open in the product topology." only invokes finite choice, a consequent of ZF (via induction).

Comment: Not necessarily: $U$ might be simply $X^\omega$, or $\emptyset$. If you said "Let $U\subseteq X^\omega$ be open in box topology, but not open in product topology" -- that would be a different story.

Comment: @tomasz : Tracing through the definitions, "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology." requires specifying a choice function.  Saying either "maybe your choice function can be simple enough to avoid Choice" or "maybe there are alternative statements that avoid the choice function" does not change the character of the statement *as written*.  If you want to discuss some other statement, you're in the wrong comments thread.

Comment: How can a definition invoke Choice? The box topology on $X^I$ is the one generated by $\tau:=\{\prod_{i\in I}U_i:U_i\subseteq X\text{ is open for all }i\in I\}$. Merely stating this definition does not invoke Choice - if you reject Choice, for instance, you might simply find that this topology coincides with the product topology (it certainly is no smaller). "Let $U\subset X^I$ be open in the box topology" - I haven't invoked Choice. I'm just considering an arbitrary element of the topology generated by $\tau$, regardless of how small or large $\tau$ is.

Comment: @Jason : I have not written that a definition invokes choice.  I have written '"Let $U \subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology." [... invokes] countable choice [...]'  This is a direct consequence of the definition you recite -- one must assume the existence of a choice of open set from infinitely many copies of $X$.  Consequently, the quoted sentence is not a sentence of ZF.  I haven't rejected choice.  I have observed that box vs. product *is* Choice-required vs. Choice-optional.

Comment: But such choices exist without assuming AC. As I pointed out, the box topology contains the product topology, so there are always a large number of choices that do not require AC. In fact, there are even sets $U\in\tau$ that do not require AC and are also not in the product topology; e.g. take $U=V^I$, where $V\subset X$ is open. The existence of this set does *not* require AC. AC tells us that choice functions always exist, but merely *using* a choice function does not invoke AC - sometimes they are constructible. E.g. the function $A\mapsto \min A$ is a choice function on $2^\mathbb N$.

Comment: @Jason : Like tomasz, you wish to discuss some sentence other than "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology."  If you wish to discuss some other sentence that conveniently restricts $U$ to be from some finitely definable subset of the box topology, you are also in the wrong comments thread.

Comment: @EricTowers No, that's the very sentence I am discussing. The box topology is perfectly well defined without AC. Saying "Let $U\subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology" therefore does not invoke AC. Once you have AC, you know the box topology is much larger, so your arbitrary element becomes far more arbitrary. But this sentences uses AC no more than saying "Let $x\in\mathbb R$" relies on the existence of transcendental numbers.

Comment: @Jason : Incorrect.  "Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$" requires one choice from one set.  This is permissible in ZF.  "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ in the box topology" requires countably many unspecified choices.  This is not permissible in ZF.  One can write the *definition* of the box topology, since it is a wff, but one cannot assert the existence of a generic element of that topology without Choice.  That one can find *some* elements with ZF shows the set exists in ZF, but ZF is inadequate to show that an arbitrary element of the topology exists.

Comment: "Let $U\subset X^\omega$ be open in the box topology" is the same sentence as "Let $U\in T$" if we define $T$ to be the box topology on $X$. You have already agreed with me that we can define $T$ without AC. So we are just making one choice. What does "the existence of a generic element" really mean? What would you call a "generic element" of $\mathbb R$? Once you have defined a set $A$ and shown it is nonempty, it is perfectly allowable to say "Let $x\in A$".

Comment: @Jason : I have agreed that the definition of the box topology is a wff in ZF.  I have not said that ZF can resolve whether the box topology is empty and whether $U \in $ box topology can ever be satisfied.  By the definitions:  Let $T$ be the topology of $X$.  Then "Let $U \subset X^\omega$ is open in the box topology" is "Let $U_1, U_2, \dots \in T$ and $U = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U_i$."  There is no theorem in ZF that gets you "$\dots"$.  The "$\dots$" require a choice axiom.  And this is all I'm writing to anyone who seems to think the Axiom of Countable Choice is a theorem of ZF.

Comment: You can very easily show $T$ (the box topology on $X^I$) is nonempty... $\emptyset\in T$, $X^I\in T$, $U^I\in T$ for any $U\subset X$ open (this requires one choice, $U$, and does not require AC), or any element of the product topology. As I have pointed out, the box topology *contains* the product topology - this fact does not require AC - so if you agree the product topology is nonempty, then you must agree that the box topology is too. You seem to claim you need AC to show the existence of a function $F:I\to S$, where $S$ is the topology on $X$, but i have *constructed* many such functions.

Comment: Also, you claim that "generic elements" of the topology on $X^\omega$ are of the form $\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}U_i$, but this is not the case - you actually need $\bigcup_{j\in J}\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}U_{i,j}$ for an arbitrary index set $J$. By your line of thinking, this would appear to require even more choices. But then... a "generic element" of the topology on $\mathbb R^2$ is $\bigcup_{j\in J}B(x_j,\varepsilon_j)$, for a countably infinite index set $J$, $x_j\in\mathbb R^2$ and $\varepsilon_j>0$. This is infinitely many "choices" - does this topology require AC, too?

Comment: ZF has no problem with existence of infinite Cartesian products: the issue it has is with their non-emptiness (but this is not an issue for Cartesian powers). You don't even need the whole ZF for that. I'm pretty sure that technically, power set, union and specification are sufficient (although you certainly need some others, like pairing and extensionality to make the notions meaningful), and  choice, replacement and foundation are irrelevant. I don't think $Q$ is what you wrote: I think you meant the set of all products of elements of $T$. That too doesn't seem to need foundation nor choice.